# Return a Json object immediately when page is called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm currently scraping a page because I need to get the latest year and mileage rate and there are no government pages available that make this easy - so I am using wikipedia.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
            // Include the library
            include('simple_html_dom.php');
            $html = file_get_html('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_mileage_reimbursement_rate');
            $data =  $html->find('table[class=wikitable]');
            //echo $html;
            if(isset($data[0])){
            echo $data[0];
            }
        ?>
        <div id="currentRate">
        </div>
            <script>
            $(window).bind("load",function() {
                var lasttd =  $('tr:last td:last').text();
                lasttd = lasttd.replace(" cents/mile", "");
                var currentAmnt = (lasttd * .01);
                var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
                alert (currentYear);
                $("#currentRate").append(lasttd);
                var currentMiles = { currentYear : currentAmnt };
                var jsonMiles = JSON.stringify(currentMiles);
                $("#currentRate").append(jsonMiles);
            });
        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do is get a JSON object sent back - because I'm trying to integrate this into an iPhone app I am creating.

Ultimately when someone goes to that page I just want a JSON object sent back so it is something like {currentYear:value} - that way when I tell my app to look to that URL it gets a clean JSON formatted object.

I'm kind of scratching my head at how best to accomplish this.

Comment: Why don't you parse that data with php and then echo as json_encode to to page without js?

Comment: Well, I was struggling to be able to get the last td, of the last tr using PHP, so I went with jquery because it was so much simpler.  I guess you're right - I could do it all with php and just use json_encode ; but it's trying to get to that data with php that has proven difficult.

Comment: Well simple_html_dom has `element$e->last_child ()` this method, I am sure you can use it to get the data.

Comment: Ah-ha!  I did.  I see now I can pull that information out of the table pretty easily.  Thanks for the suggestion - going to try and set it how I need it using PHP and do as you suggested with json_encode!

Comment: might want to take a look at http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone and handled everything via PHP with Simple Dom Parser